# Scifi book with male and female main characters. She has magic via colourful eyes and he's a warrior who collects magical stones

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book(s) over 30 years ago. It has two main heroes (one female, one male). They don't like each other at first but over the course of the books they begin to care for one another.

She has magic via colorful eyes while he is a warrior. He picks up stones that allow him to work magic in later books.  She has a cat that follows her and can speak when it wants to.

Comment: What about this is science fiction? It looks like straight-up fantasy

Comment: @Valorum I'm 90% sure my answer below is correct. If confirmed, we can change the question to read "Fantasy book..."

Answer (score 6):

This is probably Carole Nelson Douglas' **Sword and Circlet** series. "**Six of Swords**" (1982) is the first one, so matches the timeframe of over 30 years ago.

The plot elements, including the cat, are much as you describe.

Unfortunately, my answer can't be much more definitive than that. The internet is proving elusive at details, probably due to its relative obscurity. I may have a copy of Six of Swords at home. If so, I'll dig it out and expand my answer.

Edit: way back in 2003, [on rec.arts.sf.written someone asked a story ID to which the answer was Six of Swords.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rec.arts.sf.written/carole$20nelson$20douglas$20six%7Csort:date/rec.arts.sf.written/x7TEiZdWuhk/mKMbA9ZweyIJ)  The question fits the description of the heroine having magic via colorful eyes and the hero being a warrior.

> I read a book back in the 80's. If I remember correctly, focused on a
>   woman and I believe her companion.  The woman has silver eyes
>   (although i don't think it is "The Girl with Silver Eyes") and that
>   was the source of her 'power'. She was either able to work magic with
>   her eyes or had telekinetic powers. But as she used her power, the
>   silver in her eyes would diminish until she finally used all her
>   power. Her companion, I believe, was a warrior type. I've done several
>   searches on amazon and at my local bookstore but haven't come up with
>   anything yet. Any help?

In [another rasfw thread in 1997,](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/rec.arts.sf.written/owZ1H-9JvZ8/iKt8RyyigFAJ) about cat based fiction, a poster called A^3 wrote:

> Well, Carole Nelson Douglas seems to like talking cats. Her series of
>   vie books:
>
> Six of Swords, Exiles of the Rhynth, Keepers of Edanvant, Heir of
>   Rengarth, Seven of Swords
>
> features a talking cat main character

matching another clue.

Comment: That was what popped into my head as I read the question. I read the book way back in the mid-1980s or thereabouts.